# Generate attendance view/form in rails for all students

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am new to Rails and I am struggling on something which sounds easy but can not get it to work. I have two models Students and Attendances.

Student model:

```
name lastname classroom_id
```

Attendance model:

```
present:boolean absent:boolean halfday:boolean attnd_date:date student_id
```

Students `has_many :attendances` and attendance `belongs_to :student`.

I can make an entry for individual student and take their attendance however I want to generate a view where I show all the students (or show all students for a given classroom) and next to each student name I would like to show the three checkboxes so that I can mark who is present and absent in one go rather than one by one and submit the form.

Any help here is much appreciated. Using Rails 4 and ruby 2.2.0

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you clarify your question to include what you've tried so far and what the results were?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an `edit` action, where you will find the classroom for which you want to mark attendances.

```
class AttendancesController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @classroom = Classroom.find(<classroom-id>)
  end

  def update
  end
end
```

In your view `edit.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for(@classroom, url: '/attendances/:id', method: :put) do |f| %>
  <table>
    <%- @classroom.students.each do |student| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= student.name %></td>
        <td><%= checkbox_tag "attendances[#{student.id}][present]" %></td>
        <td><%= checkbox_tag "attendances[#{student.id}][absent]" %></td>
        <td><%= checkbox_tag "attendances[#{student.id}][halfday]" %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This way, when you submit the form, you will receive these params in your `update` action:

```
`{ attendances: { '1' => { present: false, absent: true, halfday: false }, '2' => { present: true, absent: false, halfday: false }, ... } }`.
```

Then you can write logic in your action to save these details to database.

Note: This is kind of pseudo code. Please check the syntax and options for different html tags.

Comment: Thanks, I have now simplified the process and just wan to get a list of all students and just create attendances for them. when I click on create attendance button it just creates one attendance and no student_id or any params are passed?

Comment: Can you show us some of your view and controller code? Only the relevant one.

Comment: i just posted the view and for controller thats what I am struggling with, at the moment its just a simple scaffold code

Comment: `
def new
    @attendance = attendance.new
  end

  # GET /attendances/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  def create
    @attendance = attendance.new(attendance_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @attendance.save
        format.html { redirect_to @attendance, notice: 'attendance was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @attendance }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @attendance.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
end
end
`

Comment: I would really appreciate your help, I am reading up a lot but it will take me some time to fully understand rails and programming.

Comment: I think you unintentionally answered your own question instead of editing your question. Ideally you should remove your answer and edit the question to include your controller code and view code. The code i suggested was the pseudo code. It may not work as is. You will have to check the syntax and options for form helpers like `checkbox_tag`. Read the docs and modify my code. Then, update your question with the errors you are getting.

Comment: As a process of learning, you should go through the docs in details, and try out as many things as possible. Don't be afraid of getting errors. Each blocker will help you learn something for the future. Debugger is your best friend. Use it wisely whenever you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jagdeep Singh for getting me up and running. I have now made the process more simple so I can get my head around. I just want to get the list of all students and create their attendances.

My view:

```
<% @students = Student.all %>

<%= form_for(:attendances, url: '/admin/attendances/') do |f| %>
  <table>
  <%= @today %>
  <th>Name</th><th>Present</th><th>Absent</th><th>halfday</th>
    <%- @students.each do |student| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= student.first_name %></td>
        <td><%= check_box_tag "attendances[#{student.id}][present]" %></td>
        <td><%= check_box_tag "attendances[#{student.id}][absent]" %></td>
        <td><%= check_box_tag "attendances[#{student.id}][halfday]" %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

when I click on create attendance button it just creates just one with record with all default params and.

I am sorry I am still learning but once I get my head around on how I can create attendances for all 10 students i have in one go.